# How to combine my two steam account into one?

Tags: steam

I have counter strike and dota2 in two different steam account..Is it possible to get the dota 2 into my counter strike steam account?

Comment: You should be asking Steam support, not us... there's nothing we can do for you and only they'd know for sure.  You're likely going to have to show proof of ownership to them to be able to do this if it is possible.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried doing this back in December 2007 and at the time it was not possible, I don't know if they have changed stance on this but I doubt it.

I got the following answer from Steam Support when asking to merge account or move games from one to the other:

> Thank you for contacting Steam Support.
>
> Per the Steam Subscriber Agreement, Steam game subscriptions / CD keys are nontransferable and cannot be reset / moved between Steam accounts.
>
> I am sorry, will be unable to assist you with this issue.